# Got an error while sending an embed discord.py

Tags: discord.py

My code is just `await ctx.send(file = f, embed=embed)`

But I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: Form data has been processed already
```

I would like to know why this error occurred and how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you maybe share more code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need a bit more information before anyone can help you. Do you mind sharing the variable declaration of embed?

Answer (score 0):

I've used embeds for quite a while, however I haven't ever seen `file = f` used in the send line of an embed. This very well might be the issue, however I can't say for certain without seeing more of the code. Here is how I usually format an embed, if it helps.

```
embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Embed title"
        )

# You can add as many of these as you want. Change the title and value fields as needed
embed.add_field(name= "Field Title", value="Field Value")

await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```